# Not enough values to unpack ValueError on seq2seq.dynamic_decode when using bidirectional_dynamic_rnn

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to build my own Neural Machine Translator based on NMT model from Google (https://github.com/tensorflow/nmt).
Everything went ok with simple encoder/decoder, added BeamSearch, then Attention. Now I'm trying to add bidirectional rnn on the Encoder and got stuck on this error:

> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)

This error is being generated on seq2seq.dynamic_decode function, after passing on a seq2seq.TrainingHelper and seq2seq.BasicDecoder. Can someone help me with this problem?

I'm being based on this particular part of the code:

https://github.com/tensorflow/nmt/blob/master/nmt/model.py#L589

My code:

```
    if encoder_type == "bidirectional":

        num_bi_layers = int(n_layers / 2)
        num_residual_layers = n_layers - 1
        num_bi_residual_layers = int(num_residual_layers / 2)

        cell_list = []
        for i in range(n_layers):
            cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(hidden_units, forget_bias=forget_bias)

            if (i >= n_layers - num_residual_layers):
                cell = tf.contrib.rnn.ResidualWrapper(cell, residual_fn=None)
                if dropout > 0.0:
                    cell = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(
                        cell=cell, input_keep_prob=(1.0 - dropout))

            cell_list.append(cell)

        if len(cell_list) == 1:  # Single layer.
            fw_cell = cell_list[0]
            bw_cell = cell_list[0]
        else:  # Multi layers
            fw_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(cell_list)
            bw_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(cell_list)

        bi_outputs, bi_state = tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(
                                                        fw_cell,
                                                        bw_cell,
                                                        encoder_inputs_embedded,
                                                        dtype=dtype,
                                                        sequence_length=encoder_inputs_length,
                                                        time_major=False,
                                                        swap_memory=True)

        encoder_outputs, bi_encoder_state = tf.concat(bi_outputs, -1), bi_state

        if num_bi_layers == 1:
            encoder_last_state = bi_encoder_state
        else:
            # alternatively concat forward and backward states
            encoder_state = []
            for layer_id in range(num_bi_layers):
                encoder_state.append(bi_encoder_state[0][layer_id])  # forward
                encoder_state.append(bi_encoder_state[1][layer_id])  # backward
            encoder_last_state = tuple(encoder_state)
```

I think that the error is at the bi rnn state extraction but what confuses me is that the source code actually works, indicating that this is correct. I executed it following the README steps and went everything ok using the entire model...

Also, you can follow the entire code on (Jupyter notebook with the entire error):

https://github.com/denisb411/seq2seq-NMT-tensorflow/blob/master/seq2seq_tensorflow_1_4.ipynb

The traceback:

https://pastebin.com/LeetGrpn

Comment: Post a stacktrace

Comment: @Maxim Please see the ipynb referenced.